# Android Developer - Putting rules in Google Play's updates

Tags: android, google-play, rules

Is there some way to put custom rules on Google Play Store? In case, I need to force the user to download latest version of my app because of some changes in its rules.

Answer (score 1):

There are *NO* ways to force the user to update the app *FROM* Play Store. If the user decided to not to update, he will not. That's it. It's completely up to him.

The only thing we can do is from out app. Like checking for updates and insist the user to update. Also we can exit the app if the user declined it.

That is the reason why we are putting facade layers in between our application and backend services. Otherwise, a change in service model will end up in a situation where we will have to maintain both services, because of different users having different versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways, Here's a one :

- Check a file from the intent, you write in it a version, if it's the same version as the app, nothing will happen, if it's newer than the app ( different ), you can show a dialog to update.
- To force him, you can set a boolean in the onCreate .

Comment: I understand, but this check could be happen only in the next version I will upload, right? I mean... I have changed some business rules in the version I want to upload now and I need the user to stop using the previous (which is the current for now) and update it, you know?

Comment: Yes, Only in the next version you upload, Add "parse" to your App, to send notifications to the users for updates, that would be better, most of the user don't check for updates.
In my online App, I've set a code to check for the App version when the request has been done, if it's the latest i can let him connect, if not i send a message to update the app.